# Can't find submitted file in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, parameters

All I'm trying to do is parse a file with Rails, but I can't for the life of me pass it through to my controller. I can't even get the file name or path to show up in the submitted params.

My form:

```
<%= form_tag({url: upload_path}, method: :patch, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field(:user, :csv, :multiple => false, class:"file-field") %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class:"btn" %>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
def upload
  file = params[:user][:csv] #params[:user] is nil
  #parse file
end
```

According to the [rails docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/file_field), I thought the file should be contained in `params[:user][:csv]`, but I must be misinterpreting something because `params[:user][:csv]` is nil, and neither "user" or "csv" show up anywhere in the params.

I want to be able to get the file path, and then using that, parse the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `file_field_tag` maybe, and also try to debug and display `params` what do you see?

Comment: have you tried adding an `abort` on your `upload_path` action and inspecting? if you're submitting that form with ajax (I do see you're not using `remote:true` but you never know), make sure you're using something like `remotipart`

Comment: What are the `params`  passed in the server log?

Comment: What's the form url? Can you please post the generated HTML-Form.

Comment: are these params `permitted`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for [file_field_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/file_field_tag)

```
<%= file_field_tag('user["csv"]', :multiple => false, class:"file-field") %>
```

Options should go after name and I don't understand what is :csv in that case if :user is name